# How to read parquets from aws bucket as pandas in jupyter using pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3

I would like to read several parquet files from an aws bucket and convert them all into a single pandas dataframe using pyspark.

```
bucket = s3.Bucket(name='mybucket')
keys =[]
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    subsrc = obj.Object()
    print(obj.key)
    keys.append(obj.key)

objects = []
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    key = obj.key
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
    objects.append(obj)
 

count = 0   
for file in objects:
    obj = s3.get_object(Bucket="my-bucket", Key=keys[count])
    obj_df = pd.read_parquet(obj["Body"])
    df_list.append(obj_df)
    count+=1

df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

But I am getting:

```
AttributeError: 's3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'get_object'
```

I am not sure how the parquet needs to be read correctly, also. Thank you!

Comment: How you are running your code? using lambda, glue, ec2 or local?

Comment: I am working in a jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

You need to write:

```
s3 = session.client('s3')
```

instead of:

```
s3 = session.resource('s3')
```